# Crop Pdf from each edge using itextshap

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to crop pdf 5 mm from every edge i.e top,bottom,right and left. I tried with below code

```
public void TrimPdf(string sourceFilePath, string outputFilePath)
{
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(sourceFilePath);
    float widthTo_Trim = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(5);

    using (FileStream output = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    using (PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, output))
    {
        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            Rectangle cropBox = pdfReader.GetCropBox(page);

            cropBox.Left += widthTo_Trim;
            cropBox.Right += widthTo_Trim;
            cropBox.Top += widthTo_Trim;
            cropBox.Bottom += widthTo_Trim;

            pdfReader.GetPageN(page).Put(PdfName.CROPBOX, new PdfRectangle(cropBox));
        }
    }
}
```

By using this code i am Able to Crop only **Left** and **Bottom** part. unable to crop top and right side 
How can i get desire result ?

Comment: i refereed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171199/crop-left-side-of-pdf-using-itextsharp

Comment: You understand that your code is enlarging the crop box on the right and the bottom which will have no visible effect if the crop box exceeds the mediabox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem by using Below code

```
public void TrimLeftandRightFoall(string sourceFilePath, string outputFilePath, float cropwidth)
{
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(sourceFilePath);
    float width = (float)GetPDFwidth(sourceFilePath);
    float height = (float)GetPDFHeight(sourceFilePath);
    float widthTo_Trim = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(cropwidth);

    PdfRectangle rectLeftside = new PdfRectangle(widthTo_Trim, widthTo_Trim, width-widthTo_Trim , height-widthTo_Trim);

    using (var output = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        // Create a new document
        Document doc = new Document();

        // Make a copy of the document
        PdfSmartCopy smartCopy = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, output);

        // Open the newly created document
        doc.Open();

        // Loop through all pages of the source document
        for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            // Get a page
            var page = pdfReader.GetPageN(i);
            page.Put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, rectLeftside);

            var copiedPage = smartCopy.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, i);
            smartCopy.AddPage(copiedPage);
        }

        doc.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `PdfCopy` is pretty destructive converning document-level information.